# Changing cell reference for a SUMIF criterion?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, sumifs, vba

I'm trying to tell Excel to change the cell reference for a SUMIF formula based on the last cell that contains a value in each row. Right now, I know I could write a nested if statement to do this for me, but it's far too unwieldy to be a long-term solution.

Example:

[image]

On a separate report, every person in this list has multiple lines recording their daily sales. On a small scale, I'd simply write a `SUMIF` that uses for A2, B3 and C4 as criteria. The scale is much much larger, so my current solution is to write out a logic check with the `SUMIF` formula folded into it.

In this case, the formula in E2 would be:

> =IF(C2="",if(B2="",SUMIF('range',A2,'range'),sumif('range',B2,'range')),sumif('range',C2,'range'))

Is there a different way to tell Excel to run the `SUMIF` with the last value found in each row?

I was hoping I could use COUNTA for each row, then have the SUMIF formula use the COUNTA value to change the criterion cell reference. I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

> =SUMIF('range',INDEX(A2:C2,MATCH("zzzzz",A2:C2)),'range')

seems worth a try.

*Edit Too long for a comment:*

I don’t really have any idea how =MATCH() works but think of it as traversing left to right while searching. When it fails to find a match it just happens to have been looking at the last entry and (conveniently!) offers that up. So the key is to look for something that *won't* be found.

For  people’s names I chose “zzzzz” as unlikely to be present. For numbers anything up to  9.99999999999999E+307 is theoretically possible and hence some people use that  (eg an hour ago [Formula to get the first cell with a numerical value from a selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752341/formula-to-get-the-first-cell-with-a-numerical-value-from-a-selection)) but I prefer a googol (1E+100) and that seems quite large enough, is much shorter – and easier to remember, even if a few `9`s more or less would make no difference, nor likely what couple of integers are after the `+`.

Comment: This is working, and I have no idea how. Would you mind explaining how the match function affects what cell's being looked up?

Thank you btw, this is great.

Comment: You can use the LOOKUP approach for text too, e.g. `=LOOKUP("zzzz",A2:C2)` - the normal equivalent to "bignum" 9.99999999999999E+307 is "bigtext" =REPT("z",255) but "zzzz" will often suffice

Comment: The reason that any of these work is a "quirk" of excel. in LOOKUP or MATCH/VLOOKUP with TRUE/1/omitted last argument excel uses "binary search", e.g. with =LOOKUP(100,A1:Y1) excel expects A1:Y1 to be sorted ascending - because of that it can look at the middle value, i.e. M1 and see if it's > 100 or not - if so it can discard the latter values, if not it can discard the A1:L1 values, so LOOKUP is quick because it only has to examine a limited number of values.....but that "tricks" the function into always returning the last value when the lookup value isn't found.......