# Excel difficult should be easy, calculate average between two non-missing entries with date-time in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to calculate average consumption for corresponding time frames (while table also contains other data). 
I have a table with date and time columns (european format) and a column with occasional counter state (fetched from text column with =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("count.state.";E1));MID(E1;FIND("count.state.";E1)+12;5);""). 
I would like to calculate average consumption automatically instead of having to manually select ranges, edit formula, then copy etc.

```
    A       B       F       G
1   2.12.   23:00   10765   =INDEX/MATCH formula should use the same data as 3 rows below 
2   3.12.   8:00    ""      =INDEX/MATCH formula should use the same data as 2 rows below 
3   3.12.   11:00   ""      =INDEX/MATCH formula should use the same data as in the row below 
4   3.12.   18:00   10769   =(10769 - 10765) / (3.12.18:00 - 2.12.23:00)
5   3.12.   23:00   ""      =INDEX/MATCH formula should use the same data as 5 rows below 
6   4.12.   11:00   ""      =INDEX/MATCH formula should use the same data as 4 rows below 
7   4.12.   15:00   ""      =INDEX/MATCH formula should use the same data as 3 rows below 
8   4.12.   18:00   ""      =INDEX/MATCH formula should use the same data as 2 rows below 
9   4.12.   23:00   ""      =INDEX/MATCH formula should use the same data as in the row below 
10  5.12.   18:00   10786   =(10786 - 10769) / (5.12.18:00 - 3.12.23:00)
```

I am learning to use Excel functions but this seems to be way way over my head. 
Anyone has a solution to this challenge? 
Thanks for your patience and effort.

Miki

Comment: So let me see if I understand you correctly, you want the formula in G to calculate average consumption only when the counter is populated in column F, and it should be based on the previous counter state and date?

Comment: Yes. I have "counter" data for consumption between two time intervals every few rows (with no regular pattern). The difference between those two counter values tells (average) consumption between the first and the second points in time.                    I thought I could find some existing solution to this problem as it seems to be of general use, for example when calculating gas milleage etc. but no such luck.

Comment: If I was doing it I would just use helper columns! I will post that way of doing it, but it would be interesting to see if others can come up with a neater way.

Comment: I was thinking about going with the following logic (but was not able to put it into any working formula):

Comment: 1. a cell in G column: lookup to find any value in F col. looking up and down until a value is found, 2. lookup date/time in the same row where values in F are found then calculate the time difference, 3. then getting average is simple.

Comment: Just BTW for anyone with YEAR-DATE calculations: I had problems with "VALUE" error when calculating time difference, the solution was to add the year (e.g. "2014") to the date. Seems obvious (now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well OK maybe not the elegant solution you're looking for but it gets the job done.

The idea is just to use helper columns to copy the date/time and counter reading from the row containing the last counter reading down through all the rows up to the one before the next counter reading like this

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(F2),F2,H1) for the counter starting in H2

=IF(ISNUMBER(F2),G2,I1) for the date/time starting in I2
```

then when you get to the row containing the next counter reading, do the calculation.

My column G contains the date & time put together using

```
=DATEVALUE(A2&"2014")+B2 starting in G2.
```

I have taken the liberty of changing the dots in the dates to slashes because of my locale.

Then the actual calculation is

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(F2),ISNUMBER(I1)),(H2-H1)/(I2-I1),"")
```

To copy the result back through each time period I have started at the bottom in cell K11 and pulled the formula upwards

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(J11),J11,K12)
```

It looks like this

[image]

However there is a useful discussion of finding the first and last cell with a numerical entry [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752341/formula-to-get-the-first-cell-with-a-numerical-value-from-a-selection) which leads to the formula

```
=IFERROR((INDEX(F2:F$11,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER(F2:F$11)+0,0),0))-(INDEX(F$1:F1,MATCH(9E+307,F$1:F1,1))))/(INDEX(G2:G$11,MATCH(1,INDEX(ISNUMBER($F2:F$11)+0,0),0))-(INDEX(G$1:G1,MATCH(9E+307,F$1:F1,1)))),"")
```

to be placed in H2 and pulled down and is a direct way of finding the answers.

I know which I prefer.

Comment: Really nicely shown and very well explained! I thought about trying with helper columns and I will use them if some more elegant solution remains elusive. It's not just about principle, I will have to show the table to other people, so easier on the eyes would be a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for positive comments. You can hide the helper columns to improve presentation. Now I think about it, you are quite right, it would be possible to use =MATCH(9E+307,F1:F4,1) to get the row of the last number before the current row (row 5 for the first calculation) and then use INDEX to get the previous counter value and time that you need in the calculation.